# How to deal with hail outdoors without special equipment?

Tags: weather, rain

Today on the short geocaching trip I've barely escaped hail storm. It wasn't very long, but I was without any special equipment. Light umbrella would survive a few minutes, and my jacket would provide a limited protection from water for a short period of time.

What are the strategies to deal with such situations? Look for the protection of big tree (yes, I know, thunders, but staying on open ground is not a good idea either)? Search a thick bush? Improvise some umbrella from sticks and leaves?

Comment: You won't have time to improvise anything, usually. I'd just get under anything I could - trees, outcropping whatever. Lacking that, if you have a pack on and the hail is large enough to cause injury, I'd get under the pack and sacrifice it to avoid the injury.

Comment: We had this happen one time but fortunately had already strung a tarp up which was enough to deflect the hail.

Answer (score 15):

I was caught by a hailstorm the weekend before last.  I was high above the tree line, the nearest trees were perhaps 20 km away, and several hours hiking from shelter.  The hailstones were not huge, but large enough to hurt.

[image: Hail above Gautelisvatnet]

Hail north of Rássevárri, above Guovdelisjávri, Narvik, Norway.

There's only one place to hide: under my backpack.  A backpack provides as much protection as is possible under such circumstances.  Hopefully it won't get damaged.  If it does, I rather have my backpack getting damaged, than myself.

This hailstorm lasted no more than 30 seconds, and I think that's common for hailstorms (although where I live, hailstorms are rare; it's the first one I've seen since I moved here in 2008).  Your backpack in available *immediately*.  If it's painful, you might not have time to search for any shelter that is more decent.

Answer (score 2):

I always keep a folded parka or thick contractor garbage bag in the bottom of my pack - rain or shine.  My pack is designed such that I can get into the bottom through a zipper quickly.

Find any way to suspend it above you.  Put two sticks in it on the sides and hold the sticks up.  Or I prefer to tie/tuck one end on the top of my pack and hold it up the front while I pack on down the trail.